# Do While Loop where I console.log a phrase is the integer between 10-0?

Tags: javascript, do-while

I'm attempting to make a function wherein I `console.log` a phrase when the number is between 0-10.

I'm getting it to print out the phrase 10 times, but to get it to pass the testing platform, I need to print it out when the number is `0`, and it's not passing.

```js
function doWhileLoop(num) {
  var i = 0;

  function incrementVariable() {
    i++
    return i;
  }
  do {
    console.log(i, "I run once regardless.");
  }
  while (incrementVariable() <= 9);
}

doWhileLoop(10);
```

Comment: What test does it need to pass? What do you mean when you say that you need to print it out when the number is 0?

Comment: where you are using the param `num`? and what needs to be printed when it is zero? your question is not clear. plz explain clearly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Where is your print statement? I don't see this code ever printing the value of `i`. When you call `incrementalVariables`, the first thing it does is advance the counter. So your print statement would have to run *before* `i++`  is ever reached.

Comment: ODO: Define a function called doWhileLoop in loops.js. The function should take an integer as an argument. Use the incrementVariable() function (you can copy it from this README) in the condition, and console log "I run once regardless." while incrementVariable() returns a number less than the parameter received. (Your condition might look something like incrementVariable() < num.) Remember that it should also console log when receiving 0 as a parameter because the do-while runs before the condition is checked.

Comment: Do you want it to print the phrase *only* when `i` is equal to `0`? If so, you need to use an `if` `then ` construct. Only print the statement when `i === 0`.

Comment: Do you want it to print at `0` and `10` inclusive (eg.0..10), or *between* meaning not including the endpoints (eg 1..9)? Or something else, like starting with `0`, but ending *before* 10 (eg 0..9)?  Please `edit` to include a sample of exactly what you are expecting (include the value of `i` for each line.  Without clarity of your question, it is technically outside the scope of SO questions, and coud be subject to closure.Even if your issue is solved, please complete the loop out of respect for the platform, those who helped, and practice for your next visit. Thanks, and Welcome to SO :-)

Comment: Just a suggestion: Never write methods that do two things: like incrementVariable() : It increments a global variable and returns it.

Answer (score 1):

Only print when `incrementVariable()` is less than the variable received:

```
function doWhileLoop(num)  {
   var i = 0; 

  function incrementVariable() {
    i++
    return i;
  }
  do {
    console.log("I run once regardless.");
   }
  while(incrementVariable() <= num);
 }
```

The point is that the loop condition must muse the parameter that is passed to the `doWhileLoop` function (`while(incrementVariable() <= num)`). And I guess the exercise is trying to show you that the code inside the `do` block will always run at least once, even if the condition in the `while` is false. So the following code runs once:

```
do {
    console.log("I run once regardless.");
   }
while(false);
```

---

### Making this not count past `9`

```
function doWhileLoop(num)  {
   if(num>9) {
      num = 9;
   }

   var i = 0; 

  function incrementVariable() {
    i++
    return i;
  }
  do {
    console.log("I run once regardless.");
   }
  while(incrementVariable() <= num);
 }
```

Comment: They dont want me to count past 10. How do I do that?

Comment: I edited my answer. You can set `num` to `9` if the number received is higher.

Comment: I mean incrementVariable < num worked. I didnt need to put an actual number. :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that @LauraOBrien! Next time, you might be interested in reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make it easier for others to understand exactly what you want and increase your chances of getting an answer. Also, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider upvoting it and accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Note, it is not clear to me whether you want it to print 10 times either `0` or `10` cannot be included. If you want it to print `0`..`10` that would actually be 11 times.  So adjust the examples below as appropriate.

Note that while troubleshooting, it is helpful to print the value `i`, as I did in the examples below.  When the program works as expected, you can then remove `i` from your `console.log` before for your final submission.

I also print out the final value of `i` when the loop is exited.
This is a god point of comparison for understanding how the loops, and the incrementation of values work in each case. It's also good to know how these loops leave variables that may be accessed later in a program, and serves as a comparison to the values printed.

The first two examples do not use a separate function just to increment, since incrementation itself is a function, and is built into the language.  It also highlights how two variations the language provides for incrementing can be exploited in useful ways to control endpoint conditions such as this.

In all cases I consistently used **`i < num`** so the comparisons would hold.
Depending on your requirements, this could also be **`i < num+1`** (equivalent to `i <= num`), or **`i < num-1`**.  Adjusting this will increase or decrease the last/highest value of `i` that is printed, (and the value `i` has after the loop ends).

**`++i`** **prints 10 times: when `i` is `0`..`9`**.
`i === 10` when the loop ends.
(using `i <= num` would print `0`..`10` and exit with value `11`)

```js
function doWhileLoop(num) {
  let i = 0;

  do {
    console.log(i, "I run once regardless. ");
  }
  while (++i < num);

  console.log("Final value of i:", i);
}

doWhileLoop(10);
```

For comparison, this version,
**`i++`** **prints 11 times: when `i` is `0`..`10`**.
`i === 11` when the loop ends.
(using `i < num+1` would print `0`..`9` and exit with value `10`)

```js
function doWhileLoop(num) {
  let i = 0;

  do {
    console.log(i, "I run once regardless. ");
  }
  while (i++ < num);

  console.log("Final value of i:", i);
}

doWhileLoop(10);
```

The difference between `++i` and `i++` is that:
`++i` the increments `i` *first*, then uses new value to determine whether to run the loop again or not.
`i++` determines whether or not to run the loop again first, based on the value `i` already has (and printed), *then* it increments `i` afterwards, but before runs the loop again (or before it exits, if the loop is not be be run again).

---

In your code, **`incrementVariable()` acts exactly like** my **`++i`** example above, because the `incrementVariable()` function call is executed *before* the `while` comparison is made.

---

Another solution would be to use an `if`-`then` to constrain your print statement.
This version prints 10 times: when `i` is `0`..`9`.
`i === 10` when the loop exits.
(In this scenario you can control the final value of the loop, and the number of times the loop is run, independent from the values that are printed.)

```js
function doWhileLoop(num) {

  var i = 0;
  function incrementVariable() {
    i++
    return i;
  }
  
  do {
    if (i < num) {
      console.log(i, "I run once regardless.");
    }
  }
  while (incrementVariable() < num);

  console.log("Final value of i:", i);
}

doWhileLoop(10);
```